# I detached packages and now I can't assign values

Tags: r, package

Oops. I unchecked a bunch of packages in RStudio and I think I unchecked a critical one that I shouldn't have touched. Now, I can't even do basic things like assign a variable a value e.g., `a <- 1`. I keep getting the error:

> ```
> Error in object.size(obj) : could not find function "object.size"
> ```

Here's the code from when I detached packages. I can only assume something in here caused the problem:

```
> detach("package:bindrcpp", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘bindrcpp’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘bindrcpp’ is imported by ‘dplyr’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘dplyr’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘dplyr’ is imported by ‘broom’, ‘recipes’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:readr", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:vtreat", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:broom", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘broom’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘broom’ is imported by ‘recipes’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:caret", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:datasets", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:DBI", unload=TRUE)
Error: package ‘DBI’ is required by ‘RJDBC’ so will not be detached
> detach("package:ggplot2", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:graphics", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘graphics’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘graphics’ is imported by ‘rpart’, ‘geometry’, ‘pls’, ‘stats’, ‘kernlab’, ‘class’, ‘dimRed’, ‘MASS’, ‘nlme’, ‘survival’, ‘lava’, ‘scales’, ‘CVST’, ‘timeDate’, ‘psych’, ‘Matrix’, ‘colorspace’, ‘randomForest’, ‘lattice’, ‘robustbase’, ‘stats4’, ‘prodlim’, ‘splines’, ‘sfsmisc’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘magic’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:grDevices", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘grDevices’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘grDevices’ is imported by ‘rpart’, ‘graphics’, ‘grid’, ‘pls’, ‘stats’, ‘kernlab’, ‘dimRed’, ‘MASS’, ‘crayon’, ‘lava’, ‘psych’, ‘Matrix’, ‘colorspace’, ‘randomForest’, ‘lattice’, ‘robustbase’, ‘stats4’, ‘sfsmisc’, ‘ddalpha’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:glue", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘glue’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘glue’ is imported by ‘tidyselect’, ‘dplyr’, ‘tidyr’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:lattice", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘lattice’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘lattice’ is imported by ‘nlme’, ‘psych’, ‘Matrix’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:magrittr", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘magrittr’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘magrittr’ is imported by ‘dplyr’, ‘stringr’, ‘purrr’, ‘recipes’, ‘tidyr’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:methods", unload=TRUE)
Error: package ‘methods’ is required by ‘RJDBC’ so will not be detached
> detach("package:randomForest", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:rJava", unload=TRUE)
Error: package ‘rJava’ is required by ‘RJDBC’ so will not be detached
> detach("package:reshape2", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘reshape2’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘reshape2’ is imported by ‘broom’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:RJDBC", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:RODBC", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:scales", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:stats", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘stats’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘stats’ is imported by ‘DEoptimR’, ‘rpart’, ‘stringi’, ‘dplyr’, ‘lubridate’, ‘reshape2’, ‘ModelMetrics’, ‘pls’, ‘munsell’, ‘kernlab’, ‘data.table’, ‘class’, ‘foreign’, ‘dimRed’, ‘MASS’, ‘nlme’, ‘crayon’, ‘survival’, ‘mnormt’, ‘nnet’, ‘withr’, ‘lava’, ‘broom’, ‘CVST’, ‘timeDate’, ‘psych’, ‘plyr’, ‘Matrix’, ‘recipes’, ‘lattice’, ‘ipred’, ‘robustbase’, ‘stats4’, ‘prodlim’, ‘splines’, ‘sfsmisc’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘magic’ so cannot be unloaded 
> detach("package:teradataR", unload=TRUE)
> detach("package:utils", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
‘utils’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘utils’ is imported by ‘Rcpp’, ‘stringi’, ‘rJava’, ‘dplyr’, ‘lubridate’, ‘reshape2’, ‘abind’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘grid’, ‘rlang’, ‘stats’, ‘data.table’, ‘foreign’, ‘dimRed’, ‘nlme’, ‘crayon’, ‘survival’, ‘nnet’, ‘tibble’, ‘lava’, ‘broom’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘timeDate’, ‘psych’, ‘Matrix’, ‘recipes’, ‘lattice’, ‘ipred’, ‘robustbase’, ‘wrapr’, ‘foreach’, ‘sfsmisc’, ‘tidyr’, ‘ddalpha’, ‘magic’ so cannot be unloaded
```

Comment: So what is your question? Either re-enable the packages (it's not clear how you "disabled" them in the first place) or reinstall R. I don't see what advantage "disabling" a package has as it should only be loaded if it's needed.

Comment: It’s exceedingly unlikely that anything you did can’t be fixed by simply restarting R into a fresh session.

Comment: @joran. You're right. Restarted and all fixed. That was stressful. Thank you for your help. Have a good night

Comment: Side point: I find it very curious in our current state of OSes and desktops and such, that the (to me) ever-so-familiar *"reboot and things will miraculously be fixed"* mantra isn't assumed to be a plausible first-step for many other things. Does "three-finger salute" (i.e., `Ctrl-Alt-Delete`) not translate figuratively if not literally to things not-about-Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object.size` is in the `utils` package:

```
> object.size
function (x) 
structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size")
<bytecode: 0x561acd777668>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

but detaching it shouldn't cause errors unless you try and use it:

```
> detach("package:utils")
> object.size(ls())
Error in object.size(ls()) : could not find function "object.size"
```

And doesn't cause assignment to fail **for me**...

```
> x = 1
> x
[1] 1
```

which makes me think RStudio (which I don't use) is at fault. I think it keeps a window of current R objects and their size, so it is probably relying on `object.size` being in the current search path, and when it isn't, most things you do will cause RStudio to complain.

As stated in comments, a restart of R (or a full RStudio restart) should clear it.